# Input Validation on JTextField + Dialogue Box

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

So my goal here is to verify the contents of a JTextField so that I can ensure the age of my Athlete object is between 6-99. Here is what I have so far.

```
JTextField ageTextField = new JTextField();

saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Integer age = Integer.parseInt(ageTextField.getText());

                Athlete athlete = new Athlete(firstNameTextField.getText(),
                        lastNameTextField.getText(), gender, age, schoolNameBox
                                .getSelectedItem().toString(), teacherBox
                                .getSelectedItem().toString(), eventBox1
                                .getSelectedItem().toString(), eventBox2
                                .getSelectedItem().toString(), null);

            }
        });
```

So basically I need a way to display an error dialogue box to the user if they have clicked "save" and the value of the JTextField is not between 6-99.

I have seen a lot of different ways of validating input on JTextFields but nothing to my specific situation. I am looking for a clean, concise way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your case something as simple as...

```
Integer age = Integer.parseInt(ageTextField.getText());
if (age >=6 && age <= 99) {
    // All is okay...
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The age is out side of the valid range of 6-99", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Would work just fine...

You could use an `InputVerifier` which will validate the field when it loses focus, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details.

You could use a `JSpinner` which will perform it's own validation and allows you to specify an valid range (6-99), see [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details

```
private JSpinner ageField;
//...
ageField= new JSpinner(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(6, 6, 99, 1));
//...
Integer age = (Integer)ageField.getValue();
```

Comment: Think you mean `this` instead of `thi` :)

Comment: This works fine the first time, however when I click the save button again I get a nullPointerException.

Comment: Which one?  Without a runnable example, there's no way I could even begin to provide suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. Use a simple if statement:

```
if(age < 6 || age > 99) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
        "Age must be 6-99",
        "Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Nit Pick: You should try and restrain you methods to a single entry and exit point, using `return` as logic branch mechanism is difficult to follow and is easily missed within code

Comment: This works fine the first time, however when I click the save button again I get a nullPointerException